# Creating minimalistic map in *.svg file format?

Tags: svg, maperitive

I am interested to obtain a .svg map file format in two colors, without labels or marks, like we have [here](http://www.architectural-review.com/Pictures/web/e/l/a/Hastings_0_380.jpg) or [here](https://img0.etsystatic.com/103/0/11407234/il_fullxfull.842215150_ey48.jpg) for example.

what I've tried:

- to use Google Styled Maps Wizard but unfortunately I'm unable to save the result into a *decent* file. I've said *decent* because, there is a possibility to use the *Static Map* button that will save a tiny image (not the desired result). Then,
- to use Maperitive applying `wireframe.mrules` and `Schwartzplan.mrules` but this is not what I'm looking for; in this case the buildings are *highlighted* (not the streets on the land color background).

I find modifying the rules in Maperitive without seeing the layers in real time, pretty uncomfy; Having said that, is there any wysiwyg plugin for this app or a standalone editor (pre-Illustrator importing phase) that can support me to achieve the described result and also can save layered svg files?

or Is there anyone that already have and want to share a Maperitive `.mrules` file that can reproduce the above mentioned result?

@Mapperz I've tried to follow the below steps but I think that there is still a misunderstanding (I have to recognise that could be my lack of knowledge).

*Download (Shapefiles)* - Done! I've downloaded 828 KB coastline shapefile, 25 MB osm2pgsql shapefiles and 36 MB imposm shapefiles.

*Load into QGIS* - In the above described archives I've found/load vancouver.osm-roads and vancouver.osm-buildings. Is that enough?

*and Change the map background to white* The map background is already white if you reffer to Project properties/General/Background color (?) *and Load the polygon and line work into QGIS* already done that at the above step *Load into QGIS*, are you reffering to something else?

*Set the layer black In the Print composer* Should I create a new Print composer I guess but then, which layer should I make it black please?

Comment: are you looking for an online or desktop solution?

Comment: as long as I can visually edit and save the layered svg file, doesn't matter.

Answer (score 5):

Like this?
Vancouver BC

[image]

Download (Shapefiles)
http://metro.teczno.com/#vancouver

Load into QGIS and

Change the map background to white
and Load the polygon and line work into QGIS

Set the layer black
In the Print composer export to svg.

Comment: The good thing here is you can save the styles and load in any osm data and achieve the same effect, works better in urban areas.

Comment: it might be the answer that I'm looking for. I'll try that and come back with news; I appreciate it. LE: Good to know thanks

Comment: _Download (Shapefiles)_  there are 3 different zip archives that include shapefiles in the filename. Should I download and load _all_ zipped files in QGIS? Regarding the _map background/polygon/line work_, can you please point the files? _Set the layer black In the Print composer export to svg_. I'm totally lost :D could you be so kind and edit  your answer using more instructions? Thanks.

Comment: And first of all I suppose that we are talking about QGIS Desktop, not QGIS Desktop with GRASS or any addon(?) like GRASS GIS 6.4.3, MSYS, QGIS Browser 2.12.0 with GRASS 6.4.3, Qt Designer with QGIS 2.12.0 custom widgets , etc

Comment: Using QGIS 2.12.0.1 Desktop (no plugins required). The metro exports will be polygons (buildings) linework (roads) you will not require points in the zip file.